# How can I see the difference in lsusb output before and after device plugin?

Tags: bash

Many times I want to compare the difference between outputs before and after plugging a device using the lsusb utility (or maybe network interfaces ifconfig utility).

Is there a simple one line way to "difference" the output of listed devices in linux, comparing before and after something is plugged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
lsusb > /tmp/lsusb.1
# plug in
lsusb | diff - /tmp/lsusb.1
```

That saves the output of the first lsusb into a file and then diffs the output of the second lsusb against the file.